# Xcode 11 > Installing (refreshing) Provisioning Profiles crashe

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I try to refresh provisioning profiles with enabled Push Notifications services. But when double clicking profiles Xcode crashes and they are not added correctly to project.

```
Date/Time:             2019-10-30 17:02:25.827 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.1 (17P1081)
Anonymous UUID:        BFF42E18-34D2-5CFE-FD55-B019B187FCC5

Sleep/Wake UUID:       4F25438D-F5E2-418A-A945-4EF7DC700FFB

Time Awake Since Boot: 7000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 11A1027
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-15403/DVTFoundation/Devices/DVTDevice.m:608
Details:  method -[DVTDevice installProvisioningProfile:] is a responsibility of subclasses of DVTiOSDevice
Object:   <DVTiOSDevice: 0x7faaaa5d0850>
Method:   -installProvisioningProfile:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7faaa5404240>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   

Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[DVTDevice installProvisioningProfile:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4   -[DVTDevicesWindowController openFileURL:withFileType:error:] (in DVTDeviceKit)
  5   -[IDEApplicationController openURLs:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
  6   -[IDEApplicationController application:openFiles:] (in IDEKit)
  7   withWindowOrderingObserverHeuristic (in AppKit)
  8   -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _openURLs:withCompletionHandler:] (in AppKit)
  9   __69-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 10   -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:] (in AppKit)
 11   -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] (in AppKit)
 12   -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] (in Foundation)
 13   -[NSAppleEventManager(DVTAssertionOverrides) swizzleDispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] (in IDEKit)
 14   _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler (in Foundation)
 15   HandleOpenDocAE (in IDEKit)
 16  0x00007fff2f3add62 (in AE)
 17  0x00007fff2f3ad489 (in AE)
 18   aeProcessAppleEvent (in AE)
 19   AEProcessAppleEvent (in HIToolbox)
 20   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 21   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 22   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 23   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 24   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 25   main (in Xcode)
 26   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called
```

I have Mac Book Pro with Xcode 11.1 installed -> here crash happens only for specific Development provisioning profile, but it installs correctly Distribution profile.

Moreover when I open this application via Network on iMac with newest Xcode 11.1 and then double-click install provisioning profiles then both Distribution and Development profile is installed there correctly.

So it seems to be something with system configuration. I have event done today update of Catalina and Xcode to newest possible versions.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have done this.
The issue was with mobile devices iPhone/iPad paired with Xcode. When I've selected 
**Window > Divices and Simulators >**

and than in left pane right clicked my physical dives iPhone, iPad and for both of them choose **Unpair Device**. Then Double-Click provisioning profile installation passed correctly and it has been added to my application project. I've spend severals ours trying to fix this. I hope it will save other people time If they encounter similar situation. :)